# How to open this paint can?

Tags: paint

I'm used to pait cans where the lid can be simply pried off using a screwdriver. However this one seems different:

[image]

How do I open it?

There are no instructions on the can itself.

Answer (score 1):

I did some poking and was able to break and remove the silver ring with needle-nose pliers. The lid beneath can now be pried open with a screw driver.

[image]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Thanks for answering your own question, but you now have [two](https://diy.stackexchange.com/users/95595/user95595) separate [accounts](https://diy.stackexchange.com/users/95602/user95602). You should use the Contact form to request that  your accounts be merged. And, keep your posts coming!

Answer (score 0):

If that is a plastic top it likely has to have the overhanging lip flexed out off a ridge on the top outside edge of the bucket.

This looks like it could be the full transition from metal paint cans to all plastic. For a while now paint cans have been a hybrid with plastic bucket but still with the crimped on metal top rim that accepts the old familiar metal paint can cover.

[image]